# How to use the ISpatialFilter interface with ArcGIS 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, c#, esri-geodatabase

From what I've heard till now:

1) ArcGIS from version 10.1 and forth will only support http connections: local connections will not be supported any longer.

2) The code

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IMapServer iMapServer = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IMapServer)ctx.ServerObject;
```

or the code

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.DataSources.ArcGISServer.MapResourceLocal mfunct = (ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.DataSources.ArcGISServer.MapResourceLocal)gisResource;
                ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IMapServer iMapServer = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IMapServer)mfunct.MapServer;
```

can't both work with an internet service connection because they require a local connection.

3) The ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.SpatialFilter object cannot be set to identify what kind of query I'd like to perform. I mean, with the ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ISpatialFilter interface you can do something like

```
spatialFilter.SpatialRel = ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects;
```

to specify what you want as result. SpatialFilter hasn't this feature. I need the ISpatialFilter spatial relationship feature.

4) If you put it all together, it figures out that you need an IMapServer-implementing object to perform the ISpatialFilter query

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFIDSet fidSet = iMapServer.QueryFeatureIDs(mapDescription.Name, layerID, queryFilter);
```

So if you read back points 1 and 2... what am I supposed to do?

I've also asked this on the official forums but still no answers.

Please help because I'm getting crazy on this.

Comment: Become a beta tester and add the questions on the beta forum. Maybe ESRI can explain how they are thinking. http://betacommunity.esri.com

Answer (score 1):

To perform a spatial query using ArcGIS Server you will want to look to the REST API.  Specifically the query operation on the map or feature server service. Here is a link to the documentation.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/index.html

This will allow you to perform a spatial query on any published feature layer.  You can also specify the spatial relationship as a parameter to the query.

It appears you are writing a .NET application.  I assume this is a web application but I am not certain. In any case you may want to look into the ArcGIS API for Silverlight for an example on how to use the query task.

- [API Documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Query_members.html)
- [Query Task Concept](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/help/index.html#/Query_task/01660000001t000000/)
- [Query Task Sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#SpatialQuery)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently using ADF to create a web application

Comment: You may want to take a look at the ESRI ArcGIS 10 and 10.1 deprecation document if you have not already. You can find that here: http://downloads2.esri.com/support/TechArticles/ArcGIS10and101Deprecation_Plan.pdf  The Web ADFs are being phased out.  The recommended path is to migrate applications to the Web APIs including JavaScript, Flex, and Silverlight.  The answer I gave above will work for any Silverlight or WPF based applications.

Comment: I'm deeply sorry but I need to work with ADF for now, because seems like we have an obsolete (and big) application :(

Answer (score -1):

So what you can do is just use the webclient class to call the REST endpoint to get your answer. Just build your URL with the query parameters you need.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string json = client.DownloadString("Url with query params");

//T is the type
T result = new T();

//You can use the serializer to convert it to an object that has the properties that   
//match the json result
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
Byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json);
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
   result = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as T;
}
```